# How to access private GitHub repositories in docker-compose?

Tags: git, docker, ssh, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  users-db:
    container_name: users-db
    build: git@github.com:lukalopusina/flask-microservices-users.git#master:project/db
    volumes:
        - '~/.ssh/github:/root/.ssh/id_rsa'
    ports:
        - 5435:5432  # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: exit 0
```

This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres

# Disable checking for known_hosts (maybe not working)
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no " > /root/.ssh/config

# run create.sql on init
ADD create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

When I run **docker-compose up** I get following error:

```
Building users-db
ERROR: Error trying to use git: exit status 128 (Cloning into '/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-build-git576570106'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
)
```

The problem is probably something with ssh permissions but I add my ssh key as mounted volume to container with (or maybe I made some mistake there):

```
volumes:
    - '~/.ssh/github:/root/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

but still it is not working. How to solve this problem?

This is permissions of ~/.ssh directory (my host machine):

```
drwx------   2 llopusina llopusina     4096 јун  7 14:22 .ssh
```

and these are the permissions of files in ~/.ssh (my host machine):

```
-rw-------  1 llopusina llopusina 3243 јун  7 14:15 github
-rw-r--r--  1 llopusina llopusina  749 јун  7 14:15 github.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 llopusina llopusina 1326 јун  7 14:35 known_hosts
```

Comment: The problem is that the volumes do not get mounted while building. They are made available only when running the container. There are additional info here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6440

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `.ssh` folder and the key you mount to the container have correct permissions (700 on folder, 600 on the key file) and owner is set to `docker:docker`

EDITED:
It looks like the problem of keys and context between docker daemon and the host. I found this unresolved issue in `docker-compose`:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2856

Where the final recommendation is:

> FYI to anyone reporting: this is a known issue. <...> the solution is
>   to do the git clone on the client side. We don't consider it
>   high-priority, but PRs are always welcome.

Comment: i added list of permissions to question description. Is there some problem with my permissions?